# Checking if a subspace is a submodule.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory

Consider the regular representation of the cyclic group $\{ e,a,a^2 \} $ with the standard basis. I would like to figure out if the subspace $W$ spanned by $u=e_1-e_2, v=-e_1+e_3$ is a submodule. Consider the action of the three group elements on each basis vector:
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
e u=u, & e v=v \\
a u=e_2-e_3=-u-v, & a v=-e_2+e_1=u \\
a^2 u=e_3-e_1=v, & a^2 v=-e_3+e_2=-u-v
\end{array}
$$
Since the action of the group on each of the basis vectors is in the subspace, we can conclude that it is submodule. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. A shorter proof is: $W={\rm span}(u,au,a^2u).$

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you.